# Unable to change xcode dependencies to iOS SDK 4.1

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, xcode

I download some sample code from deitel, but it refuse to build. I already went to Project -> Edit Project Settings and changed the Base SDK to Device iOS 4.1
[image]

I also tried to set the Project -> Set Active SDK, but the menu option is disabled and says "Base SDK Missing".

If I try to build, I get an immediate error:
[image]

If I create a project form scratch, everything works perfectly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the "Base SDK" pulldown on the left side; switching it to something else will cause those new settings you chose to take effect.

Also, in that picture you sent over, you're only changing the settings for "Release", while it's clear from the other picture that you're building `Debug` mode. Change the dropdown configuration to "All Configurations", make the same changes, change the dropdown options as mentioned above, and Build!

Answer (score 1):

Check if your are also defining the sdk in the target.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with a couple of things I've downloaded since XCode 3.2.5 came out.

I ended up having to throw the project.pbxproj into TextMate (or another text editor) and replace all instances of

"SDKROOT = iphonesimulator4.1;"
with 
"SDKROOT = iphonesimulator4.2;"

and instances of 
"SDKROOT = iphoneos4.1;"
with
"SDKROOT = iphoneos4.2;"

and save it, and then I could get changes made in XCode to stick.